# How can I easily filter out unwanted fields in JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I build some records in a database table. When I show it to users, some fields I don't want to show. This is an example: https://aircode.cool/icm3kf2jje

```
// @see https://docs.aircode.io/guide/functions/
const {db} = require('aircode');

module.exports = async function (params, context) {
    const table = db.table('persons');

    if(!(await table.where().findOne())) {
        const students = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            students.push({
                name: `students${i}`, 
                score: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), 
                info: {_private: 'something', public: {_foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}}
            });
        }
        await table.save(students);
    }
    const result = await table.where({score: db.gt(60)}).limit(10).find();
  return {
   result,
  };
};
```

I don't want to show the fields which name starts with an underscore, like `info:_private` and `info:public:_foo`.

How can I easily filter out such unwanted fields in result?

In this case, I can only filter these fields one by one:

```
for(const [k, v] in result) {
    delete v.info._private;
    delete v.info.public._foo;
}
```

Is there a better way to efficiently and universally accomplish this task?

Comment: JSON != JavaScript Object.  This question has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the key starts with '_'

```
Object.keys(your_obj).forEach(k => {
   if(k.startsWith('_')) delete your_obj[k];
})
```

Comment: Try to create solution for nested object on your own. If you are stuck anywhere, we can help you again.

Comment: This won't work recursively as OP wants

Answer (score -1):

Try lodash omit, it is a cleaner way to maintain the keys that you want to exclude.

https://lodash.com/docs/#omit

Comment: Your answer as it is does not solve op's problem.